# Run unix commands using Jsch maven

Tags: java, maven, unix

Execute Unix commands using Jsch maven

I'm trying use this code for performing the following steps, but it's not working.

1. String command1 = "ls -ltr"
2. String command2 = "cd /test/user/"
3. String command3 = "./test.sh"

[Reference Link.](http://www.journaldev.com/246/java-program-to-run-shell-commands-on-ssh-enabled-system)

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");

            Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
            ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command1);
// From above command does work! It lists the files.
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command2);
```

But the last line doesn't work--nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to connect to the channel, e.g.

```
channel.connect();
```

Then you need to read the response. There is an example at http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html

```
InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
while(true){
  while(in.available()>0){
    int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
    if(i<0)break;
    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
  }
  if(channel.isClosed()){
    if(in.available()>0) continue; 
    System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
    break;
  }
  try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
}
```